# EV3 brick freeze during run big program

Tags: ev3, ev3-g

EV3 brick sometimes freezes while executing huge programs and do not react on buttons and bluetooth (connect, start/stop program). Only way to continue work is hard reset.
We discovered that freeze depends on medium motor blocking.
Is there any way to fix this?

Program:
http://puu.sh/iQuFg/678d3add5f.ev3

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

My kids have this exact same problem when a program reaches a certain size.  Parts of the program that previously worked just fine begin to systematically cause the brick to lock up.  We have found, as ridiculous as this sounds, the simple act of adding a variable read immediately before the motor block which seems to cause the brick to lock up will fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the medium motor block at On For Degrees mode? If you did, the motor would attempt to spin and run until it reaches the degrees set in the block. You could replace the block with wait for X seconds.

Comment: No, it is not because of motor block.

Comment: lol..............................................................................